# How to know the size of a const array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sizeof

given the following code:

```
const myStr codesArr[] =  {"AA","BB", "CC"};
```

myStr is a class the wraps `char*`. 
I need to loop over all the items in the array but i don't know the number of items.
I don't want to define a `const` value that will represent the size (in this case 3)

Is it safe to use something like:

```
const int size = sizeof(codesArr) / sizeof(myStr);
```

what to do?

Comment: Is this question c or c++? For c++ I would really recommend using `std::array` (or `std::tr1::array` if your compiler isn't c++11) instead of builtin arrays. And likely using `std::string` instead of whatever `myStr` does

Comment: Optionally you could also do `sizeof(codesArr) / sizeof(codesArr[0]);`, with the restriction mentioned by Luchian Grigore.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `int size = sizeof(codesArr) / sizeof(myStr);` as long as you don't pass it as parameter to a function, because then the array will decay into a pointer and lose size information.

You can also use a template trick:

```
template<typename T, int sz>
int size(T(&)[sz])
{
    return sz;
}
```

Comment: sizeof returns a size_t, but we all use it with int.
Does it work because of the implicit cast?

Comment: @Maroun85 Yes, there's an implicit conversion (not a cast per se). This conversion will not cause any problem as long as the size can be represented as an int.

Comment: Your `size()` function should be `constexpr` in C++11, or use macro technique in C++03, so that it can be used as constant expression.

Comment: @Nawaz not possible; `constexpr` functions can only have literal-type parameters, even if they aren't used.

Comment: @ecatmur: Oh I didn't know that. Anyway, in that case, macro technique  is the way.

Comment: is there any particular reason *not* to use `size_t`?

Comment: @JensGustedt no, I guess `size_t` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 38):

The safe and clear way to do this is to use [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) (since C++11):

```
const size_t size = std::extent<decltype(codesArr)>::value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way(pre c++11) to get size of an array is given at [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx). It is a **convoluted template trick**, but has many advantages over other approaches as is discussed in the above link. The method is to use the following macro+function:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
char ( &_ArraySizeHelper( T (&array)[N] ))[N];

#define countof( array ) (sizeof( _ArraySizeHelper( array ) ))
```

Its advantages, among others, are that it is purely a **compile time operation**, which is better than doing it in run time, and , **before c++11's constexpr**, is the only method that allows you to use the result of the operation **as the size of another array** ( since its a **compile time constant**

Comment: What's so convoluted about it?  It is a straightforward use of template argument deduction.  (If you want convoluted template tricks, look at some of the Boost sources.)

Comment: (Of course, there is the fact that your exact code has undefined behavior, since it contains a symbol which starts with an underscore followed by a capital letter.)