# How to determine constexpr size of C array typedef without sizeof, similar to std::size

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Is there something similar to std::size that works with the typedef of C array in C++17 or later available in STL?

To calculate a constexpr number of elements in typedef CArray defined like this:

```cpp
typedef double MyCArrayType[20];
```

This works, but I don't want to declare a variable:

```cpp
MyCArrayType arr;
constexpr size_t sz = std::size(arr);
```

This works, but I prefer not to specify element type:

```cpp
constexpr size_t sz = sizeof(MyCArrayType) / sizeof(double);
```

I'd like something similar to this, if it is in STL already:

```cpp
constexpr size_t sz = std::size<MyCArrayType>();
```

Comment: @RetiredNinja This requires a variable declaration, I clarified my question that I don't want to declare a variable. I found that std::extent works for me.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/13375713/2986286

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I've found what I need. The std::extent works for my case

```
typedef double MyCArrayType[20];


constexpr auto sz = std::extent<MyCArrayType>::value;
//or
//constexpr auto sz = std::extent_v<MyCArrayType>;
```